# Oracle MICROS Simphony Transaction Services Gen2

Tags: oracle, integration, documentation

following this doc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/industries/foodbeverage/simphony/omsstsg2api/index.html
Why does the Auth API ({authBaseURL}/oidc-provider/v1/oauth2/) consistently respond with a 200 status code for all necessary requests like /authorize, /oauth2/signin, and /oauth2/token,
but attempts to access the API ({baseURL}/api/v1/) using the generated token result in a 403 Forbidden error?

I tried with same auth URL but it does not work and get 404 Error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved? I'm running into the same issue.